# Minimum Bounding Box by Area using ArcObjects

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I'm trying to calculate the minimum bounding geometry by area for a polygon in arcobjects. I know that the the [MinimumBoundingGeometry class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Overview/004700003304000000/) is exposed but I was hoping that this functionality was available at the IGeometry level compared to the feature class level.

[This](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000) is what I'm trying to calculate; RECTANGLE_BY_AREA, for an IGeometry. I know you can quickly get the envelope as well as the convex hull in ArcObjects but I dont know how to get the minimum bounding box by area. Any thoughts or direction would be great, thanks!

Comment: What's the difference between the envelope and RECTANGLE_BY_AREA? I don't see what you're trying to achieve, can you include a picture?

Comment: Good illustrations here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000